# Journey Builder(Custom Activity): InteractionStudio RestActivity failed validation for Save

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, rest, activity, custom-activity

I came to you guys because I don't understand a problem on a Custom Activity in Journey Builder, here is the error : [image]

I am a beginner so sorry if it is a stupid question. I thought it was that my answer when I save my activity but I return a status 200 in my backend.

```
app.post(/\/activity\/(save|publish|validate)/, (req, res) => {
   console.log('SAVE/VALIDATE/PUBLISH');
   console.log(req.body);
   return res.status(200).json({success: true});
});
```

Maybe I don't understand the error correctly.
Also my req.body is empty and I don't know why.
I give to you my code for save in CustomActivity.js :

```
function save () {
    //var eventDefinitionKey = $('#select-entryevent-defkey').val();
    let campaignNameKey = $('#select-campaign-name').val();
    let ftpServerKey = $('#select-ftp-server').val();
    let dataExtensionKey = $('#select-data-extension-key').val();

    payload['arguments'] = payload['arguments'] || {};
    payload['arguments'].execute = payload['arguments'].execute || {};


    payload['arguments'].execute.inArguments = [{
        'serviceCloudId': '{{Event.<YOUR ENTRY EVENT DEFINITION KEY>.\"<EVENT DATA ID PATH>\"}}',
        'campaignNameKey': campaignNameKey,
        'ftpServerKey': ftpServerKey,
        'dataExtensionKey': dataExtensionKey,
    }];

    payload['metaData'] = payload['metaData'] || {};
    payload['metaData'].isConfigured = true;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(payload));

    connection.trigger('updateActivity', payload);
}
```

I'm using Heroku to run my web application.
Thanks for your help and if you have any questions, tell me and I will answer quickly.

EDIT : my config file

```
{
"key": "30...(my key)9",
"metaData": {
  "icon": "images/icon.png",
  "iconSmall": "images/icon_small.png",
  "isConfigured": true
},
"type": "REST",
"lang": {
   "en-US": {
      "name": "MyElefant",
      "description": "FTP server Cloud"
    }
},
"workflowApiVersion": "1.1",
"configurationArguments": {
   "applicationExtensionKey": "30..(my key)9",
   "save": {
       "url": "https://test-app-perso-ikumbi.herokuapp.com/activity/save",
       "verb": "POST",
       "body": "",
       "useJwt": false
    },
"publish": {
  "url": "https://test-app-perso-ikumbi.herokuapp.com/activity/publish",
  "verb": "POST",
  "body": "",
  "useJwt": false
},
"validate": {
  "url": "https://test-app-perso-ikumbi.herokuapp.com/activity/validate",
  "verb": "POST",
  "body": "",
  "useJwt": false
}
},
"wizardSteps": [
{
  "key": "eventdefinitionkey",
  "label": "Event Definition Key"
}
],
"outcomes": [
{
  "key": "rest-1-outcome-1",
  "next": "<key of next activity>"
}
],
"userInterfaces": {
   "runningModal": {
     "url": "runningModal.html"
    },
   "runningHover": {
     "url": "runningHover.html"
    }
},
"arguments": {
  "execute": {
    "inArguments": [],
    "outArguments": [],
    "url": "https://test-app-perso-ikumbi.herokuapp.com/activity/execute",
    "verb": "POST",
    "body": "",
    "header": "",
    "format": "json",
    "useJwt": false,
    "timeout": 90000
  }
},
"edit": {
  "url": "https://test-app-perso-ikumbi.herokuapp.com/index.html",
  "height": 400,
  "width": 500
}
}
```

Comment: Is there additional output in your browser's JavaScript console? Additionally, did you try using the [Salesforce Marketing Cloud - Developer Tools (Google Chrome Extension)](https://markus.codes/sfmc-chrome-devtools) that shows additional information for errors in Marketing Cloud?
Did you try manually sending a POST-request to your endpoint and checking the result?
As it looks like you are using a modified version of [my example activity](https://github.com/mslabina/sfmc-servicecloud-customsplit) but without JWT verification, did you change the body-parser middleware to not use JWT?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer,  I indeed use the example activity, I will try disabling JWT , I looked over Marketing Cloud extension and nothing is shown on the "error messages". I will try also the manual POST-request, I will answer when I have done that

Comment: I did change the JWT in the body-parser and the error is still there, I did a POST-request with postman and I have this as an answer on https://test-app-perso-ikumbi.herokuapp.com/activity/save : {
    "success": true
}

Comment: I can show you if you want my config file because I did maybe a bad use of the config file.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the config file as this could be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where the problem come from. It was from the Data Extension in Journey Builder because as soon as I changed it, there is no more errors and execute requests are made. I don't why it was doing that exactly, maybe because the original DE was used in an other activity so it made my journey crash. Thanks Markus for the help :)